# Example 2, Chpt 4 Advanced Mathematics (I)

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \frac{x+2}{2x^3+3x^2+3x+1}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I can get it down to this:

$$\int \frac{2}{2x+1} - \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}\, \mathrm{d}x $$

I can solve the first part but I don't exactly follow the method in the book.

> $$ = \ln \vert 2x+1 \vert - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\left(2x+1\right) -1}{x^2+x+1}\, \mathrm{d}x $$
>   $$= \ln \vert 2x+1 \vert - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{x^2+x+1} + \frac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} $$

For the 2nd part:

I tried $ u = x^2+x+1 $ and $\mathrm{d}u = 2x+1\, \mathrm{d}x$  that leaves me with $\frac{\mathrm{d}u - 1}{2} = x\, \mathrm{d}x$  which seems wrong.

because $x^2+x+1$ doesn't factor, I don't see how partial fractions again will help.

$x = Ax+B$ isn't helpful.

Comment: What is the question? What you are doing is perfectly fine, you are a small substitution from the end.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I can't seem to get it work out. What is that small subtitution.

Comment: My favourite would be $x+\frac{1}{2}=w\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$. If you wish, I can explain it in two steps. But in the meantime, solve the problem with this substitution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post indicates some difficulty with finding $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}$. We solve a more general problem. But I would suggest for your particular problem, you follow the **steps** used, instead of using the final **result**.

Suppose that we want to integrate $\dfrac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}$, where $ax^2+bx+c$ is **always** positive, or always negative. We complete the square.

In order to avoid fractions, note that equivalently we want to find
$$\int \frac{4a\,dx}{4a^2 x+4abx+4ac}.$$
So we want to find
$$\int \frac{4a\,dx}{(2ax+b)^2 + (4ac-b^2)}.$$
Let 
$$2ax+b=u\sqrt{4ac-b^2}.$$
Then $2a\,dx=\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\,du$.
Our integral simplifies to
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\int\frac{du}{u^2+1},$$
and we are finished.

Comment: I don't follow the $u$-substitution: $2ax+b=u\sqrt{4ac-b^2}$ I have never seen substitution  where you have a constant time $u$. I have checked all the books I have have, and haven't seen that before.

Comment: Then write instead "let $u=\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}$." Exactly the same thing. Or do the substitution in two steps, first let $2ax+b=w$.  I wrote the substitution the way I did because follows the intuition more closely. If you wish I will add at the end of the post the mechanical details of the substitution, but they really are mechanical, and quick.

Comment: What you think mechanical, I think magic.

Comment: As I wrote in the post, try it on your problem. Start with $\frac{4}{4x^2+4x+4}=\frac{4}{(2x+1)^2+3}$, let $\sqrt{3}u=2x+1$, and you are close to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$x+\frac12=\frac{\sqrt3}2\tan t,dx=\frac{\sqrt3}2\sec^2tdt$$
$$\frac12\int\frac{dx}{\left(x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34}=\frac{\sqrt3}4\int\frac{\sec^2tdt}{\frac34\tan^2t+\frac34}=$$
$$\frac{\sqrt3}4\int\frac{\sec^2tdt}{\frac34\sec^2t}=\frac{\sqrt3}3\int dt=\frac{\sqrt3}3t+C$$

Now just solve for $t$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Could you explain how you can use $ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\tan t$ for substitution?

Comment: @MaoYiyi The idea is to use the property that $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$.  A series of manipulations could get it into the form $k\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=k\tan^{-1}u$.  This just gets there in one step.